# ReactJS + Firebase Session Persistence. Keep persistence until last tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Having a bit of an issue currently. I have a user management system set up where you can log in and etc using firebase. Currently we have the firebase persistence set to local so you are able to open new tabs and still be logged in on the new tab. However I have a use case where I want to log out a user once all tabs are closed.

Case 1: User logs in, opens new tab is logged in on both tabs

Case 2: User logs out new tab and is still logged in on original tab (Also close original and be logged in on new tab)

Case 3: User closes all tabs or closes browser. When going back to the web app they should be logged out

I have tried firebase persistence set to session however this does not allow for new tabs as you will be logged out when opening a new tab.

Any ideas or suggestions on a method on getting around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use localStorage to store like a counter of opened tabs. While closing if this counter is 1, do a callback before closing (for ex in hooks, on the useState, return is called while component is destroying), then erase the local storage, call the API to revoke the token ?

Comment: I have investigated into this. I added a counter in the componentdidmount of app.js. However it was noted that this would also increment when it is refreshed.

Comment: And do you decrease the counter with a componentWillUnmount callback ?

Comment: I can understand where you are coming from however the issue still exists. For instance if you were to refresh it would decrease the value to 1 causing you to log out. Then it would reload with you logged out and add 1 to the counter again.

Comment: Well maybe an idea (without any security because if the user edit the value manually maybe it will not close) would be while only one page remaining to save the value of Date.getTime() and when you comeback check if there are more than 20 seconds passed and in this case log out the user ?